# Gobble page numbers

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

In my document I have 5 pages that consist of the chapter name. I want these pages not to have page numbers displayed *and* not to contribute to the page numbering.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

> ..., p5, p6, blank page, p7, p8, ...

By using `\thispagestyle{empty}` on the blank page and I get:

> ..., p5, p6, blank page, p8, p9, ...

where the blank page has been included in the numbering.

I then tried to use `\pagenumbering{gobble}` on the blank page and then `\pagenumbering{arabic}`

on the next consecutive page but the numbering was reset to give:

> ..., p5, p6, blank page, p1, p2, ...

How can I prevent the gobble input from resetting the page numbering?

Comment: If you don't need to do this many times you can use the `empty` and set up the `page` counter by means of `\setcounter{page}{7}` or something else.

Comment: I was looking the way to have a page with empty numbering. thank for the answers I saw here. I found my problem and solve using \pagenumbering{gobble}. thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a little example of what you want. Note

- `\thispagestyle{empty}` suppresses the page number on the current page.
- You can fiddle with the page numbering using commands like `\addtocounter{page}{-1}`. (You could instead use `\setcounter{page}{\thepage-1}`, but that requires loading the `calc` package, which lets you evaluate numerical expressions like `\thepage-1`.)

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

First page
\clearpage
Second page
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
\addtocounter{page}{-1}
Third page

\end{document}
```

Comment: @JohnWickerson -- i didn't actually mean to remove the other suggestions.  they're valid, and under some circumstances might be preferable, so keeping them in the list could be useful.

Comment: What is the difference between using

\setcounter{page}{\thepage-1}

and 

\addtocounter{page}{-1}

after the clearpage input? Both seem to give the desired effect, I'm just curious as the which would be best to use if I'm repeating it throughout the document. I expect there is not real advantage one has over the other...?

Comment: They have exactly the same effect, but `\addtocounter{page}{-1}` is a little bit shorter, and as @barbarabeeton says, doesn't require any extra packages to be loaded.

Comment: @Alastair: Please consider clicking on the tick mark next to an answer to 'accept' it, so that this question can be marked as resolved. :)

Answer (score 11):

If you want to keep `hyperref` happy, in case you use it, change the page number representation:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{nopage}
\newenvironment{nopage}
 {\clearpage\stepcounter{nopage}%
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{NP\arabic{nopage}}%
  \thispagestyle{empty}}
 {\clearpage\addtocounter{page}{-1}}

\begin{document}

First page

\begin{nopage}
\chapter{A chapter}
\end{nopage}

Second page

\begin{nopage}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\end{nopage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I implement your solution in an environment that spans more than one page, my typesetting for `\thepage` actually includes the NP at the bottom of the page.  I thought the `\thispagestyle{empty}` would have been applied repeatedly for every instance of the renewed `\thepage`.  Why does this show up?  Thanks!  Oh, the counter part keeping track of elapsed pages works fine though - which is why `\thispagestyle{empty}` not being repeated surprised me.

Comment: @EngBIRD You've chosen the wrong road, probably, but without an example it's difficult to say more

Comment: Great thanks! Time permitting I will ask this in a new question then.