# Table of Contents labels not directing hyperlinks to correct page

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, hyperref, counters, parts

Being only a LaTeX novice I may have introduced a bit of customizing code renewing part formats and adjusting numberings which may have messed up the ability for hyper-references accuracy in heading to the correct target.

In short:  despite having distinct labels on each hierarchy object duplicate names create problems in the hyperlinks between the TOC and the desired section:  E.G.

Part 1

A <-> 1 -> goes to page 1 in Part 1

Part 2

A <-> 2 -> goes to page 1 in Part 1

Problematic Code - Reduced to MWE

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
    %=========================================================================================================================================
    % PACKAGES REQUIRED FOR CONTROLLING AND CONFIGURING TABLE OF CONTENTS AND OTHER LISTS
    %=========================================================================================================================================
    \usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
        \setcounter{secnumdepth}{6} 
        \setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
        \renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize \scshape}
    \usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
    \usepackage{etoolbox} % or xpatch

    \usepackage{chngcntr}           %http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume
        \counterwithin*{chapter}{part}  %http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54383/how-to-reset-chapter-and-section-counter-with-part
        \counterwithin*{section}{part}
        \counterwithin*{section}{chapter}

        \counterwithin*{figure}{part}
        \counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

        \counterwithin*{table}{part}
        \counterwithout{table}{chapter}

    %http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=4293
    \renewcommand\part{%    
        \if@openright
        \cleardoublepage
        \else
        \clearpage
        \fi
        \thispagestyle{empty}%
        \if@twocolumn
        \onecolumn
        \@tempswatrue
        \else
        \@tempswafalse
        \fi
        \null\vfil
        \secdef\@part\@spart
    }

    %http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103926/part-title-in-list-of-figures-and-tables
    % initial definitions of the chapter info (name and number)
    \def\thischaptertitle{}\def\thischapternumber{}
    \newtoggle{noFigs}
    \newtoggle{noTabs}


    \apptocmd{\@part}%
    {\gdef\thisparttitle{#1}\gdef\thispartnumber{\thepart}%
        \global\toggletrue{noFigs}\global\toggletrue{noTabs}}{}{}

    % the figure environment does the job: the first time it is used after a \chapter command, 
    % it writes the information of the chapter to the LoF
    \AtBeginDocument{%
        \AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
            \iftoggle{noFigs}{
                \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{part}%
                    {\protect\numberline{\thisparttitle}}{}{3.2em} }
                \global\togglefalse{noFigs}
            }{}
        }%
        \AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
            \iftoggle{noTabs}{
                \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline{part}%
                    {\protect\numberline{\thisparttitle}}{}{} }
                \global\togglefalse{noTabs}
            }{}
        }%
    }


    %/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    % setup environment to permit the removal of page numbers while still continuing sequence when resumed and keeping hyperref happy   // 
    %/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    %http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112782/gobble-page-numbers
    \newcounter{nopage}
    \newenvironment{nopage}
    {\clearpage\stepcounter{nopage}%
        \renewcommand{\thepage}{NP\arabic{nopage}}%
        \thispagestyle{empty}}
    {\clearpage\addtocounter{page}{-1}}

    %_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

    \newenvironment{paper}{%
        \begin{sloppypar}
            \global\let\oldthesection\thesection
            \renewcommand{\thesection}{\@arabic\c@section}%
        }{%
        \end{sloppypar}
        \global\let\thesection\oldthesection
    }


    %=========================================================================================================================================
    % PACKAGES REQUIRED FOR HYPERLINKS AND HYPER-REFERENCES
    %=========================================================================================================================================
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
    \usepackage{bookmark}

    %http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42927/converting-from-latex-to-html-using-htlatex
    \usepackage{hyperref}   %\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        %bookmarks=false,         % show bookmarks bar?
        unicode=true,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat's bookmarks
        pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat's toolbar?
        pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat's menu?
        pdffitwindow=true,     % window fit to page when opened
        pdfstartview={FitV},    % fits the height of the page to the window:  or fits the width of the page to the window  FitH
        pdftitle={My title},    % title
        pdfauthor={Author},     % author
        pdfsubject={Subject},   % subject of the document
        pdfcreator={Creator},   % creator of the document
        pdfproducer={Producer}, % producer of the document
        pdfkeywords={keyword1} {key2} {key3}, % list of keywords
        pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
        colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
        linkcolor=black,          % color of internal links (change box color with linkbordercolor)
        citecolor=black,        % color of links to bibliography
        filecolor=black,      % color of file links
        urlcolor=black          % color of external links
    }

    \bookmarksetup{
        numbered,
        open
    }

    \usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

    %_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
    \listoffigures      %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
    \listoftables       %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

    \begin{sloppypar}% must be after abstract and title page

        \part{Author Introduction}
            %\setcounter{chapter}{0}
            \chapter{First}\label{P1I}
            \chapter{Second}\label{P1II}
            \chapter{Third}\label{P1III}


        \part{Paper 1}\label{First Paper}%
        %\setcounter{chapter}{1}
        \begin{paper}
            \section{Introduction}\label{pp1I}
            \section{Materials and Methods}\label{pp1M}
            \section{Results}\label{pp1R}
            \section{Discussion}\label{pp1D}
            \section{Conclusion}\label{pp1C}
            \section{References}\label{pp1B}
        \end{paper}     



        \part{Paper 2}\label{Second Paper}%
        %\setcounter{chapter}{1}
        \begin{paper}
            \section{Introduction}\label{pp2I}
            \section{Materials and Methods}\label{pp2M}
            \section{Results}\label{pp2R}
            \section{Discussion}\label{pp2D}
            \section{Conclusion}\label{pp2C}
            \section{References}\label{pp2B}
        \end{paper}


        \part{Global Discussion}
            \chapter{First}\label{PLI}
            \chapter{Second}\label{PLII}
            \chapter{Third}\label{PLIII}

    \end{sloppypar} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the typical `hypertexnames=true` issue. Change to `hypertexnames=false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the way link destination names are generated by `hyperref`. If the counter value is used, this will lead to errors, since *Chapter 1* occurs four times in this document, each time the chapter counter has a value of **1** then.

The relevant portion to change is `hypertexnames=false` (initial default value is *true*)

From the manual of `hyperref`:

> Usually problems with duplicate destination names can be solved by an
>   appropriate definition of \theH. If option hypertexnames is
>   disabled, then a unique artificial number is used instead of the
>   counter value. In case of page anchors the absolute page anchor is
>   used. With option plainpages the page anchors use the arabic form. In
>   both latter cases \hyperpage for index links is affected and might not
>   work properly.

This happens, for example, when the chapter counter is reset by the `\part` (macro, e.g. the part counter is `refstepped`) as is done in the OP's example. In a 'standard' setup, the counter number is *not* reset, just advanced in every `\part`.

So either set `hypertexnames=false` either in `\usepackage[...]{hyperref}` or later on in `\hypersetup`. This will also omit any warnings about duplicate destination labels.

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
    %=========================================================================================================================================
    % PACKAGES REQUIRED FOR CONTROLLING AND CONFIGURING TABLE OF CONTENTS AND OTHER LISTS
    %=========================================================================================================================================
    \usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
        \setcounter{secnumdepth}{6} 
        \setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
        \renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize \scshape}
    \usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
    \usepackage{etoolbox} % or xpatch

    \usepackage{chngcntr}           %http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume
        \counterwithin*{chapter}{part}  %http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54383/how-to-reset-chapter-and-section-counter-with-part
        \counterwithin*{section}{part}
        \counterwithin*{section}{chapter}

        \counterwithin*{figure}{part}
        \counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

        \counterwithin*{table}{part}
        \counterwithout{table}{chapter}

    %http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=4293
    \renewcommand\part{%    
        \if@openright
        \cleardoublepage
        \else
        \clearpage
        \fi
        \thispagestyle{empty}%
        \if@twocolumn
        \onecolumn
        \@tempswatrue
        \else
        \@tempswafalse
        \fi
        \null\vfil
        \secdef\@part\@spart
    }

    %http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103926/part-title-in-list-of-figures-and-tables
    % initial definitions of the chapter info (name and number)
    \def\thischaptertitle{}\def\thischapternumber{}
    \newtoggle{noFigs}
    \newtoggle{noTabs}


    \apptocmd{\@part}%
    {\gdef\thisparttitle{#1}\gdef\thispartnumber{\thepart}%
        \global\toggletrue{noFigs}\global\toggletrue{noTabs}}{}{}

    % the figure environment does the job: the first time it is used after a \chapter command, 
    % it writes the information of the chapter to the LoF
    \AtBeginDocument{%
        \AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
            \iftoggle{noFigs}{
                \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{part}%
                    {\protect\numberline{\thisparttitle}}{}{3.2em} }
                \global\togglefalse{noFigs}
            }{}
        }%
        \AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
            \iftoggle{noTabs}{
                \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline{part}%
                    {\protect\numberline{\thisparttitle}}{}{} }
                \global\togglefalse{noTabs}
            }{}
        }%
    }


    %/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    % setup environment to permit the removal of page numbers while still continuing sequence when resumed and keeping hyperref happy   // 
    %/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    %http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112782/gobble-page-numbers
    \newcounter{nopage}
    \newenvironment{nopage}
    {\clearpage\stepcounter{nopage}%
        \renewcommand{\thepage}{NP\arabic{nopage}}%
        \thispagestyle{empty}}
    {\clearpage\addtocounter{page}{-1}}

    %_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

    \newenvironment{paper}{%
        \begin{sloppypar}
            \global\let\oldthesection\thesection
            \renewcommand{\thesection}{\@arabic\c@section}%
        }{%
        \end{sloppypar}
        \global\let\thesection\oldthesection
    }


    %=========================================================================================================================================
    % PACKAGES REQUIRED FOR HYPERLINKS AND HYPER-REFERENCES
    %=========================================================================================================================================
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
    \usepackage{bookmark}

    %http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42927/converting-from-latex-to-html-using-htlatex
    \usepackage{hyperref}   %\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        %bookmarks=false,         % show bookmarks bar?
        unicode=true,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat's bookmarks
        pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat's toolbar?
        pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat's menu?
        pdffitwindow=true,     % window fit to page when opened
        pdfstartview={FitV},    % fits the height of the page to the window:  or fits the width of the page to the window  FitH
        pdftitle={My title},    % title
        pdfauthor={Author},     % author
        pdfsubject={Subject},   % subject of the document
        pdfcreator={Creator},   % creator of the document
        pdfproducer={Producer}, % producer of the document
        pdfkeywords={keyword1} {key2} {key3}, % list of keywords
        pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
        colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
        linkcolor=black,          % color of internal links (change box color with linkbordercolor)
        citecolor=black,        % color of links to bibliography
        filecolor=black,      % color of file links
        urlcolor=black,          % color of external links
        hypertexnames=false
    }

    \bookmarksetup{
        numbered,
        open
    }

    \usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

    %_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
    \listoffigures      %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
    \listoftables       %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

    \begin{sloppypar}% must be after abstract and title page

        \part{Author Introduction}
            %\setcounter{chapter}{0}
            \chapter{First}\label{P1I}
            \chapter{Second}\label{P1II}
            \chapter{Third}\label{P1III}


        \part{Paper 1}\label{First Paper}%
        %\setcounter{chapter}{1}
        \begin{paper}
            \section{Introduction}\label{pp1I}
            \section{Materials and Methods}\label{pp1M}
            \section{Results}\label{pp1R}
            \section{Discussion}\label{pp1D}
            \section{Conclusion}\label{pp1C}
            \section{References}\label{pp1B}
        \end{paper}     



        \part{Paper 2}\label{Second Paper}%
        %\setcounter{chapter}{1}
        \begin{paper}
            \section{Introduction}\label{pp2I}
            \section{Materials and Methods}\label{pp2M}
            \section{Results}\label{pp2R}
            \section{Discussion}\label{pp2D}
            \section{Conclusion}\label{pp2C}
            \section{References}\label{pp2B}
        \end{paper}


        \part{Global Discussion}
            \chapter{First}\label{PLI}
            \chapter{Second}\label{PLII}
            \chapter{Third}\label{PLIII}

    \end{sloppypar} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I omitted a screen shot, since it does not provide anything different as the OP's original code.