# How to STOP not suppress page numbering?

Tags: page-numbering

I am currently writing my thesis using Overleaf. My university's format guide for the thesis requires that some pages, such as the copyright page, to be neither counted nor numbered. How can I do this on Latex? I know I can use \thispagestyle{empty} to hide page numbering but the page is still included in the count. But how can I stop LaTeX from counting a certain page?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112782/293154